# PHP session handling to save to database

Tags: php, database, session

Learning PHP, the most frustrating hurdle for me seems to be weeding through outdated tutorials, blog and forum posts to find relevant, modern guides.

I want to understand how to implement saving sessions data to databases the right way. However, most of the instructions I can find regard custom session handlers, and seem to be many years old, and this concerns me. I don't want to waste my time learning outdated procedures.  Are custom handlers still the way to accomplish this? Are there better/newer modes of storing sessions to db's?  I would greatly appreciate anyone taking the time to point me in the right direction. Many thanks!

Comment: I recommend just using a good framework. Symphony and Laravel for example, are good ones. There's only so much you can do with the built-in PHP sessions.

Comment: Yes, custom handlers are still the way to go if you want to do that. Your first step should always be the [official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php) [at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). Create a class that implements the native `SessionHandlerInterface` and set it as a handler. There's a reasonable example from 1 year ago in the comments for the `session_set_save_handler()` function in the docs.

Comment: @apokryfos - Thanks. I certainly have every intention of utilizing frameworks. I would just like to learn as much as possible in core php before doing so.

Comment: @rickdenhaan - Thanks, I appreciate the response.Really want to make sure I'm learning modern practices.

Answer (score 3):

To confirm what @rickdenhaan was saying in comments, custom handlers is the right way to go.

PHP doesn't provide a lot of different session handles. Maybe because Zend (which supports PHP) provide Zend Session tools.

To avoid reinventing the wheel you have to options :

### Use a framework

That will handle all of this kind of stuff for you : session, MVC, ORM, config files etc

Most of the time this is the right choice for a new project, and Symfony and Laravel are great projects to start.

### Use external modules

If you want a more modular approach, you can import externals modules with composer and create something that suits your particular needs.

This can be a great approach to refactor an existing project (either based on an old framework, or on legacy code)

And in this case, you still don't reinvent the wheel, you can use Zend Tools to handle your session : 
https://github.com/zendframework/zend-session

Install it with composer and start working with it. Use it with built-in php tools `session_set_save_handler()`

I hope this answer your question in a broader way.